# Pass props with <Link> to Component with validation in ReactRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have a following React Router:

```
 <Route path="/" component={Main}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="post/:postName" component={Post} />
 </Route>
```

In my `Home` component I have a `<Link>` to `post/SamplePost` route.

Clicking `<Link>` redirects me to `Post` component where I validate `props.title` like this:

```
Post.propTypes = { title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired }
```

I know that my `postName` specified in URL is accessible via `this.props.route.postName` however, is it possible to somehow assign this postName to `this.props.title` before props validation?

**Update:**

Why cannot I just validate `this.props.route.postName`?

Imagine scenario where I want to fetch post content from a dictionary/map/object/store/whatever where `postName` is a key, and content is a value, and it would like to validate, that this value `isRequired`.

Comment: Why don't you validate ```this.props.route.postName``` directly? Try:

```Post.propTypes = { title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired, route.postName:  React.PropTypes.string.isRequired }```

Comment: This was just an example. Imagine case where I'd like to fetch something else basing on `route.postName` as a key, for instance, content of a post by it's title and also validate that with `body: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired`

Comment: Then what you are fetching is not a prop, but correlated data. Note also that fetching data is an async operation. I'd suggest validating your data as a callback function.